# Foursquare API, searching tips result order

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm searching all tips at a certain location with a keyword.
this is the call:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/tips/search?ll=41.9,12.5&query=donuts&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=VERSION
I would like to know how those tips are ordered?

Since I'm getting just a part of all tips (up to 500) I can't order them by distance, because there may be other tips in the upcoming 500 more that could be closer.
Is there a way to get tips ordered by distance?

The API doesn't report the total number of tips, we can't implement a solid paging system.
How can I get to know the total number of tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can add such parameter as radius, to show closer venues:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/tips/search?ll=41.9,12.5&query=donuts&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=VERSION&radius=1000
```

Comment: @kleopatra this link is an example of url request with parameter, which author needs.

Comment: ahh ... misunderstood your intention :-) Maybe you could format as code, to clarify? But maybe only me not seeing it at first sight ;-)